# Cant run sudo commands in shell_exec

Tags: php, linux, captiveportal

I'm creating a Captive Portal in PHP, a site where users connecting to the wifi will be requested some information before having their access authorized.

I've already configured iptables to redirect unauthorized traffic to the login page. In the login page, after the user provides the necessary information, i need to run the following command:

```
exec("/usr/sbin/iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING 1 -m mac --mac-source $mac -j RETURN");
```

this command requires root access, so when i exec it in terminal with root user or use "sudo iptables..." it works, and the access is authorized. So the command is working.

But i can't make this command work in PHP. I've added apache user (www-data) to sudoers file, and added it to sudo group. It seems to have worked, because if I 'impersonate' www-data in linux terminal (`su -s /bin/bash www-data`) and run the exact same command in terminal it works.

In my php page I called:

```
$result = shell_exec("sudo /usr/sbin/iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING 1 -m mac --mac-source $mac -j RETURN");
```

But it returned nothing.

If i execute a non root command its working :

```
$mac = shell_exec("$arp -a ".$_GET["nome"]); $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
preg_match('/..:..:..:..:..:../',$mac , $matches);
```

How can i make this command work in php?

Comment: Capture stderr at least. [How can I debug exec() problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/12199353)

Comment: Do not give user programs root privileges. Security 101. Send credentials to a root process which checks them and then grants access including iptables.

Comment: @mario , I'm doing that, in $result variable, but it returns nothing.

Comment: @stark I'm not giving the program full root privileges, I've added a entry in sudoers file to allow the user to run this specific iptables command. Any other command would not authorized.

Comment: In the end I was able to make it work using this PHP SSH library: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/. I connected via SSH and run the program. (Should I edit my question to inform this or post an answer myself?)

Comment: If the information you want to add solves your problem but doesn't answer the question I think it's better to do neither (or just remove the question altogether).